# AppCode ignores "Right to Left Pseudolanguage" setting from Schema Configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, right-to-left, appcode

I'm writing app that supports right-to-left languages. To test the app in simulator I set up "Right to Left Pseudolanguage" in Schema Configuration in xCode:

[image]

When run the app from xCode everything goes as expected and system draw ui elemnts in right-to-left manner. The problem is when I try run app from AppCode, because it seems to ignore this settings and app looks like as common.

After every change in AppCode I have to switch to xCode to run simulator. 
It's annoying. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've debugged which parameters are given to input when xCode start the process in simulator. The final answer should be:

```
-AppleTextDirection YES 
-NSForceRightToLeftWritingDirection YES
```

**Don't forget about dash in the beginning of the parameter name**.

Answer (score 3):

If you can pass arguments to the app on launch in AppCode you need to specify:

```
-NSDoubleLocalizedStrings YES
-AppleTextDirection YES
-NSForceRightToLeftWritingDirection YES
```

This should give you the desired Right to Left Pseudolanguage effect.

Comment: I paste it into "program arguments" in AppCode configuration, but it doesn't work.